# Replace complex string in several files

Tags: sed, string, replace

A hacker got into a web server and added this string (removed some characters for security purposes and **added line breaks** for readability) in all `index.php` files:

```
<?php 
eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eF5Tcffxd3L0CY5WjzcyNDGGMV4+1dSwqSqzU0LQGAJCPCMM='))); 
eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eF5LK81LLsnMzKx+JjNW0rgUAqDUUxQ==')));  
eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eF6VlMmy/3sMxOez/iJOojHFT0Ig/8jlTymmN/I='))); 
?>
```

I have tried using the `sed` command to remove it (replacing it with nothing) but it is nearly impossible to define a working regular expression with such a huge string.

Is there another way, maybe reading the string from a .txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumung you don't use these tricks anywhere, why not this (appropriately executed, using `sed -i` and maybe `find -exec ...`, which was not part of your question, was it?)

```
$ sed 's/eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode(.*)));//' << EOF                     
> <?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eF5Tcffxd3L0CY5WjzcyNDGGMV4+1dSwqSqzU0LQGAJCPCMM=')));eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eF5LK81LLsnMzKx+JjNW0rgUAqDUUxQ=='))); eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eF6VlMmy/3sMxOez/iJOojHFT0Ig/8jlTymmN/I=')));?>
> EOF
<?php  ?>
```

...you can afterwards deal with the empty `<?php  ?>`s (which don't hurt much, do they?).

**Edit** removed line breaks to make sure it fits to the situation described.

**Edit2** You'd be better off just replacing everything with a (*known good*) backup, probably, if you've got one.

**Edit3** I just caught the "all index.php files" bit. You can thus try something like

```
find /path/to/wwwroot -name "index.php" -exec sed -i regex {} \;
```

Comment: I have used some backups but for some files I had to do it this way. Thanks sr_! It worked great.